# Git merge after git rebase?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I was reading this article http://supercollider.github.io/development/git-cheat-sheet.html, which proposed the following workflow:

```
git checkout master
git pull --rebase # update local from remote
git rebase master chgs
git checkout master
git merge chgs
git push
```

I'm sure I don't understand how this works and why it is useful.

Doesn't the third line, `git rebase master somechanges`, put commits from `chgs` after the last commit from `master` but without merging them, and leaves `HEAD` pointing to the latest commit from `chgs`, like this:

```
(master-commit-n-1)<--(master-commit-n)<--(chgs-commit-k-1)<--(chgs-commit-k)<--HEAD
```

Does that leave me with `chgs` checked out? That's why I need to check out `master` again?

And why do we need to merge the changes into master?  Doesn't that make a graph like this:

```
(master-commit-n-1)<--(master-commit-n)<--(chgs-commit-k-1)<--(chgs-commit-k)
                                        \.(master-with-merged-chgs-commit-k)<--HEAD
```

I don't see why the top fork is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order:

> Doesn't the third line, `git rebase master somechanges`, put commits from `chgs` after the last commit from `master` but without merging them ...

Yes, assuming `somechanges` is a typo for `chgs` (the referenced page uses yet more spellings).

> and leaves `HEAD` pointing to the latest commit from `chgs`

Yes but only indirectly: `HEAD` literally contains `ref: refs/heads/chgs`, i.e., you are left with branch `chgs` checked-out.  It's `chgs` itself that points to the latest commit.

> Does that leave me with `chgs` checked out?

Yes.

Specifically, the "current branch", the one printed as `on branch ...` when you use `git status`, is just whatever `refs/heads/branch` is in the file `HEAD`, when `HEAD` contains `refs: refs/heads/branch`.  Running `git checkout branch` first makes sure it's OK to update the work tree, then does that and puts you on that branch, by rewriting `HEAD`.

Internally, `git rebase upstream branch` invokes `git checkout branch`, so the whole process starts by getting you on the branch.

> And why do we need to merge the changes into master? Doesn't that make a graph like [snipped]?

You need<sup>1</sup> the `merge` to move the label.

I prefer to draw the commit graph with letters, or sometimes just little `o` nodes, with either single dashes or short arrows between them to denote the parenting relationships.  And, stealing (but modifying) a leaf from `git log --graph --oneline --decorate`, I add the branch name on the right with a longer arrow.  If `HEAD` names the branch, I add `HEAD=` in front.

What you have right after the rebase can thus be drawn as:

```
... - E - F               <-- master
            \
              G - H - I   <-- HEAD=chgs
```

Here the commit labeled `F` is the tip of branch `master`, so `master` points to `F` (and `F` points back to `E` and so on).  The tip of branch `chgs` is commit `I`; `I` points back to `H`; `H` points back to `G`; and `G` points back to `F`.  And of course `HEAD=chgs` so you're on that branch.

Once you `git checkout master`, that updates your work tree as usual, and makes `HEAD` point to `master` which points to `F`.  Then if you run `git merge chgs`, git looks to see if it's possible to do a "fast forward" merge:

```
... - E - F               <-- HEAD=master
            \
              G - H - I   <-- chgs
```

A fast forward merge is possible when the current commit (`F`, in this case) is already an ancestor of the target commit (`I`).  If so, the branch label is peeled off the current commit and simply pasted onto the target commit:

```
... - E - F
            \
              G - H - I   <-- chgs, HEAD=master
```

(There's no longer any ASCII-art-reason to keep the kink in the drawing [from `F` down-and-right to `G`], but I kept it for visual symmetry.)

As [Cupcake noted in his faster answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22770531/1256452), you can force a real merge with `--no-ff`.  I would draw this as:

```
... - E - F ------------- M   <-- HEAD=master
            \           /
              G - H - I       <-- chgs
```

In either case (fast forward, or "real merge"), once this is done, you can safely delete the branch *label* `chgs`, as all of its commits are find-able by starting at `master` and working backwards (along both branches if a "real merge").  Or, you can keep it and add more commits to it, if you prefer.

An interesting note here is that in this particular case the resulting *work tree* associated with commit `M` is exactly the same as the one for commit `I`.  The key difference is that this creates an actual merge commit (a commit with multiple parents).  The first parent is whatever commit was on the branch before—in this case, commit `F`—and the remaining commits (just the one commit `I`, here) are the branches being merged-in.

(You can override this—the work-tree being the same, I mean—with yet more merge flags, but in this case you would not want to.  That sort of thing, overriding the work-tree, is mainly meant for "killing off" a branch while retaining the history: sort of a "look, we tried this and it didn't work" message to someone looking at the code next year.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Or don't need, if you don't want to move the labels.  However, if you intend to `push` your work back to someone, or let them `pull` it from you, they will look at your labels.  It's nice for them if you arrange your labels nicely for them.  But it's always up to you.

Answer (score 3):

## # 1

> Doesn't the third line, `git rebase master somechanges`, put commits from `chgs`
>   after the last commit from `master` but without merging them, and leaves `HEAD`
>   pointing to the latest commit from `chgs`, like this:
>
> ```
> (master-n-1) <- (master-n) <- (chgs-k-1) <- (chgs-k) <- HEAD
> ```

The effect of rebasing `chgs` onto `master` is equivalent to merging `master` into `chgs`, because the state of your code at the last commit will be equivalent to the state after a `merge`.

## # 2

> Does that leave me with `chgs` checked out? That's why I need to check out
>   `master` again?

Yes.

## # 3

> And why do we need to merge the changes into master?  Doesn't that make a graph
>   like this:
>
> ```
> (master-n-1) <- (master-n) <- (chgs-k-1) <- (chgs-k)
>                           \
>                            (master-with-merged-chgs-k) <- HEAD
> ```

No. Because you rebased `chgs` on top of `master`, git will recognize that the last commit on `chgs` effectively represents the state of `master` "+" `chgs`, so it just "fast-forwards" the `master` branch to the tip of `chgs` without making a merge commit:

```
(n-1) <- (n) <- (k-1) <- (k) <- HEAD/master/chgs
```

If you wanted to ***force*** git to do a merge-commit instead, you could pass the `--no-ff` flag to `merge`:

```
git merge --no-ff chgs

# Results in this

(n-1) <- (n) <- (k-1) <- (k) <- chgs
            \               \
              --------------(merge) <- HEAD/master
```

## # 4

> I don't see why the top fork is useful.

It's useful for updating feature branches with upstream changes from `master`, without creating a bunch of redundant merge commits in the feature branch. The end result is that your development history becomes simpler and easier to work with, instead of containing a bunch of extra merge commits that you don't really need, and which just make the history more complicated and harder to manipulate.

Answer (score 1):

The following explains in more detail what each of these commands is doing.

> git checkout master

Switches to the `master` branch.

Suppose locally we have this (where `*` indicates the current branch):

```
M1 -- M2 = master*
       \__ C1 = chgs
```

---

> git pull --rebase

Updates local `master` branch from the remote branch, rebasing any local changes that have been made to the `master` branch so that they come after the remote changes.

Suppose this gives us a new M3 change:

```
M1 -- M2 -- M3 = master*
       \__ C1 = chgs
```

---

> git rebase master chgs

Rebases changes from the local `chgs` branch so that they follow on from the local `master` branch (but remain in their own branch). Also changes to the `chgs` branch.

```
M1 -- M2 -- M3 = master
             \__ C1' = chgs*
```

---

> git checkout master

Switches back to the `master` branch.

```
M1 -- M2 -- M3 = master*
             \__ C1' = chgs
```

---

> git merge chgs

Merges `chgs` into `master`.

```
M1 -- M2 -- M3 ------- M4 = master*
             \__ C1' __/ = chgs
```

---

> git push

Pushes these changes to the origin.